# Can't create an AKS cluster with Azure Pass subscription

Tags: azure-container-service

When I try to create an AKS cluster with the portal, I'm facing the following problem:

[image]

This problem got "solved" when I scaled-down the cluster to just one node. But when I tried to browse the cluster, it wasn't possible. It was giving me timeouts. It seems that cluster was not health anyway.

Now, when I try to create a new cluster with just one node (A0), it's taking foreveeeeeer! Look:

[image]

I'm wondering if there's any special limitation for the Azure pass subscription. But it's weird because when I take a look at the subscription quota, I'm not even close to reaching the limit.

This is a new and clean subscription, I have nothing else there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I was using an A0 instance type.

AKS cluster **nodes need at least 3.5GB of memory**, that's why it had errors or took so much time to be created (it never finished actually).

I end up using a Standard A2 v2 (2 vcpus, 4 GB memory)